# Should I use static field or SharedPreferences for storing custom objects?

Tags: java, android, static, sharedpreferences

I am working on an Ecommerce application where I have to store list of products to cart.

First, I worked with static field to store list of custom objects (products) but problem is when application went behind the scene for some time, static fields looses it's data.

Then, I decided to store products to `SharedPreferences` but problem is it doesn't take custom objects, so first I serialize it with `Gson` then store it and when ever I want it, I deserialize it.

Problem for using `SharedPreferences` is I have to do some extra work (serializing and deserializing). What should I do? Is there any other easy way to store data globally.

Comment: no you have to do Serializing and Deserializing if you want to save complete object at a time. Another option will be to save each object separately as a string in shared preferences

Comment: what is the best practice for saving cart items

Comment: You are already doing that

Answer (score 0):

Prefer SharedPreferences over static field. But you can use SQLite, ActiveAndroid or any other ORM to store data.

ActiveAndroid is comparatively easy to implement and process data.
ActiveAndroid: https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid